# Integrating Visual studio 2013 with OpenCL and ATI GPU

Tags: visual-studio-2013, opencl

I have no idea so I decided to write here. I'm trying to integrate my vs2013 with openc(ati GPU).

I did everything according to this guide:
[tutorial](http://kode-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/11/setting-up-opencl-in-visual-studio_1.html)

But when I run project I see message like:

> Program called project1 stopped
>   Why ?

Comment: Pay attention to bitness of your operating system, cpu, compiler options and binary folders. What is your gpu?

Comment: My GPU is ATI mobiliti radeon hd 5730

Comment: Try to provide absolute paths to headers & libraries, I usually do that on similar setup.

Comment: I know. But program build corectly, and didn't run. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was - Incompatible graphics card